# Specifying java.naming.provider.url for an inbound endpoint configuration in jndi.properties

Tags: wso2, jms, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I have an inbound endpoint configuration and I want to specify `java.naming.provider.url` value inside of the `jndi.properties` which will make me configure the inbound endpoint dynamically according to the provider urls of the different environments that I have.

Here is my axis2.xml configuration of ActiveMq

```
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
   <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:6092</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
   </parameter>

   <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:6092</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
   </parameter>

   <parameter name="default" locked="false">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">failover:tcp://localhost:6092</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
   </parameter>                                          
</transportReceiver>
```

and this is my inbound endpoint configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="inboundEP" onError="conf:sequences/om.esb/om.esb-faultSQ.xml" protocol="jms" sequence="inbEPSQ" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">example_request</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">3</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">conf/jndi.properties</parameter> 
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/json</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.SharedSubscription">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

In jndi.properties file, I tried to specify `java.naming.provider.url` in this way:

```
# register some connection factories
# connectionfactory.[jndiname] = [ConnectionURL]
connectionfactory.QueueConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5675'
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5675'


java.naming.provider.url=failover:tcp://localhost:6092
# register some queues in JNDI using the form
# queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = example.MyQueue

# register some topics in JNDI using the form
# topic.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
topic.MyTopic = example.MyTopic
```

but in WSO2 console, I have the following error:

```
Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport not scheme specified: [conf/jndi.properties]
```

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests 'java.naming.provider.url' should be a URL, so something starting with '(protocol)://'

Since tcp://localhost:6092 worked for you in your other configuration, try this instead:

```
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:6092</parameter>
```

What happens in JNDI is that first your "java.naming.factory.initial" class is created (which is org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory in your case) and then you can use any of the provider urls supported by this class. Depending on your provider it could support different URL types (tcp:, file:, ssl:, ...). ActiveMQ supports vm: and tcp: - when specifying tcp: it will load this JNDI configuration using TCP from that broker.

Comment: Hi, I have no problem with this way, but the value of the java.naming.provider.url will be different according to the environments. So, I need to use a dynamic structure for the inbound configuration. I tried to read the java.naming.provider.url value from a file in the governance folder ($registry:gov:/javaNamingProviderURL) but I cannot see the url inside of the file in the inbound endpoint configuration. In WSO2 console, I see only the path of the file in the java.naming.provider.url value.

Comment: What you could do is use a file-based JNDI implementation: set java.naming.factory.initial to "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory" and java.naming.provider.url to be "file://conf/jndi.properties"  - see for example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-6767/aeqbb/index.html